# How to publish test results from the following path in azure : Users/runner/work/1/s/

Tags: azure-pipelines

When I run azure pipeline, test results are storing in following path. Is there a way we can access the below path and publish test results.

Path:  Users/runner/work/1/s/

Answer (score 0):

You should check predefined variables on azure devops.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

If your test results are published inside sources folder you will need the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` variable.

Attaching a useful article about how agent works and predefined variables that you may find useful.

https://blog.geralexgr.com/devops/how-azure-devops-pipelines-agent-works

Answer (score 0):

You could use [publish test result task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml) to publish your test result like below.

[image]

Or you can also use [copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy your test result from Users/runner/work/1/s/ to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, then publish the test result by using [publish pipeline artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic).

[image]